# How to make query that find inside of find in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a document as below in Mongodb.

```
{
  "vatInfo":{
        "company": "apple"
  },
  "type": "manager",
  "parent": "123"
}
```

And I have another document in same collection as below.

```
{
  "type": "member",
  "parentId": "123",
  "id": "3"
}
```

And when I make `client.find({id: 3, type: 'member'})`, I want to get this that finds vatInfo automatically inside of find.

```
{
  "type": "member",
  "parentId": "123",
  "id": "3",
  "vatInfo":{
    "company": "apple"
  },
}
```

How should I make aggregate for this find? I dont want to make double find.
Thank you so much for reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the aggregation pipelines for that.

[$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) - find the parent documen.

[$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) - join the document from the other collection.

[$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) - modify the structure of the result.

```
// collection `client`
{
    "vatInfo":{ "company": "apple" },
    "type": "manager",
    "parent": "123"
},
{
    "type": "member",
    "parentId": "123",
    "id": "3"
}

// query example
db.getCollection('client').aggregate([
    { $match: { 'id': '3', 'type': 'member' } },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'client',
            localField: 'parentId',
            foreignField: 'parent',
            as: 't01'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            '_id': 0,
            'type': 1,
            'parentId': 1,
            'id': 1,
            'vatInfo': { $arrayElemAt: [ "$t01.vatInfo", 0 ] }
        }
    }
])

// result
{
    "type" : "member",
    "parentId" : "123",
    "id" : "3",
    "vatInfo" : {
        "company" : "apple"
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand both of the documents are inside the same collection.

Comment: @SuleymanSah thanks for noticing (somehow I missed it), I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

To add the field of another document, you can use populate in Mongoose :

For this to work you need to have a reference in your schema between the client document and the parent document :

```
const clientSchema = Schema({
  [...]
  parentId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ParentCollection' }
});
```

Then, you can use populate anywhere in your code :

```
client.findOne({id: 3, type: 'member'}).populate('parentId');
```